# C#, Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, serial-port

I have the following code :

```
void serialport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string serialData = serialport.ReadExisting().Replace("/n", "");
        string[] splitSerialData = serialData.Split(new Char[] {','}); //Split up the data

        this.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
            {
                this.temperatureLabel.Text = splitSerialData[0];
            }));
    }
```

And it works fine, but when I do :

```
void serialport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string serialData = serialport.ReadExisting().Replace("/n", "");
        string[] splitSerialData = serialData.Split(new Char[] {','}); //Split up the data

        this.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
            {
                this.temperatureLabel.Text = splitSerialData[0];
                this.lightLevelLabel.Text = splitSerialData[1];
            }));
    }
```

It does not work and says "Index was outside the bounds of the array".

Comment: Are you sure it's `/n` and not `\n`?..

Comment: Are you sure there's a comma in your string? Hint: There's not.

Comment: You should check number of string in splitSerialData e.g. by using splitSerialData.Length > 2.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting this error because `serialData` does not contain a comma.  The resulting array therefore contains one element, and the expression `splitSerialData[1]` throws the IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: This is what my Arduino is sending to the program:        Serial.print(temperatureC);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(lightLux);
    Serial.print("/n");

Comment: Data in looks like:     16.37,180.29/n

Comment: @Thomas debug your program. It looks like the event is firing *before all the characters have been received.* If that is true, you'll need a way to cache the data until everything has arrived, and then process it.

Answer (score 3):

This means that the split returns exactly one element  - the entire string. There is no array element at index 1, so

```
splitSerialData[1]
```

throws the `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.

This, in turn, means that the string that you pass does not contain a comma `','` character.